# Passing firebase data from ListView to seperate activity editText

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-adapterview

I am attempting to click a specific item within a listView and opening its value in a separate activity 
the ListView is filled dynamically from firebase

I have the following and it doesn't seem to work, this is the activity passing the data

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Try using the answers from the latest questions because will help send the entire object to the intent.

Comment: If your data set is larger than just a few rows and/or you have other views such as `ImageView` incorporated in your list it will be worth considering the `RecyclerView`. It takes some effort to understand how to implement it, but in the end it is a more powerful list element and worth the effort.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you have to do is send the data(Parcelable if it's an object) from the list via the intent to the detail activity.